# Filter nodes by value inside of variable(RTF) xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to filter the nodes by a set of conditions one of those conditions is that  the node value must exists inside of an variable (result tree fragment)

I currently use contain with a string and the node value but i want to use a variable.

I have tried to use something like this inside the xpath with no result.

```
exsl:node-set($varfilter)/item[contains(.,@code)]
```

XML Example

```
<root><row><cell>text</cell><cell>Value1</cell></row></root>
```

XSLT

```
    <xsl:variable name ="lastantecesor" 
select="exsl:node-set($data)/row[1]/cell[contains('value1,value2,value3',.)][last()]"/>
```

Variables

```
    <xsl:variable name="data">
      <root>
       <row><cell>text</cell>Value1<cell></cell></row>
      </root>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="varfilter">
      <item code="Value1"/>
      <item code="Value2"/>
    </xsl:variable>
```

Comment: Your variable `var1` is in XSLT 1 a result tree fragment containing two `item` elements with a `code` attribute. It is not clear where you want to use it as a node set as nowhere you use `exsl:node-set($var1)`, instead you have `exsl:node-set($varfilter)` without showing any declaration of that variable and you have `exsl:node-set($data)` without showing declaration of that variable either. And your XML example has `CELL` elements while your path uses `cell`. So you might want to clarify your examples and make them consistent.

Comment: I fixed the post ,and yes the var1 (varfilter) is going to be a nodeset, $data is a variable containing the shown xml example